# UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains many `UIImageView`s, UILabels, etc... the labels are much longer that the `UIScrollView`, but when I run the app, I cannot click and scroll down...

Why might this be?

Thanks

Comment: New 3/26/2013
I stumbled on an easier way to do this without code (setting contentSize) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649607/1705353

Answer (score 175, accepted):

It's always good to show a complete working code snippet:

```
// in viewDidLoad (if using Autolayout check note below):

UIScrollView *myScrollView;
UIView *contentView;
// scrollview won't scroll unless content size explicitly set

[myScrollView addSubview:contentView];//if the contentView is not already inside your scrollview in your xib/StoryBoard doc

myScrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size; //sets ScrollView content size
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let myScrollView
let contentView

// scrollview won't scroll unless content size explicitly set

myScrollView.addSubview(contentView)//if the contentView is not already inside your scrollview in your xib/StoryBoard doc

myScrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size //sets ScrollView content size
```

I have not found a way to set contentSize in IB *(as of Xcode 5.0)*.

Note:
If you are using Autolayout the best place to put this code is inside the `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method .

Comment: Don't forget to set `myScrollView.delegate = self` ALSO, if this still isn't working, the answer below this one has GREAT advice (go to your xib/StoryBoard and make sure "AutoLayout" is disabled). Pro-Tip: You can also include `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` in your .h file if you wish to do things like programmatically scroll your UIScrollView.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw you should have added an answer so I could have given you a +1 :) AutoLayout was the issue with me....drove me insane for like 4 hours.

Comment: Putting code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` made it work for me.

Comment: For me the issue was that it didn't need to scroll, as everything fit on the screen.

Answer (score 122):

If you cannot scroll the view even after you set **contentSize** correctly,
make sure you **uncheck** "Use AutoLayout" in Interface Builder -> File Inspector.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set **contentSize** in **viewDidLayoutSubviews:**, and it will be applied after the autolayout completes.

Comment: @" Chris Vasselli" slove my issue.. GR8..:-)

Comment: Hours of my life wasted before finding this jewel-like suggestion. A big thankyou goes out to you sir.

Comment: Thanks Chris Vasselli, don't understand why I need this in one VC and not the other though..

Comment: Chris' comment should be a separate answer!

Comment: That fixed the issue for me [along with setting contentSize in IB]

Comment: Although I'm supposed to avoid comments like +1 and thanks, here you are Chriss, +1 THANK YOU!

Comment: Autolayout was my issue...was a PITA to figure it out...would have never figured it out had I not found this  THANKS!

Comment: This is very true answer thanks but can't figure out why? Autolayout is the option related to the screensize

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Vasselli! With Auto Layout enabled, it won't work in viewDidLoad but it does with viewDidLayoutSubviews!

Comment: I think Apple should rename the "AutoLayout" to "AutoFail". I lost more time figuring out bugs related to the AutoLayout than saving time using AutoLayout.

Comment: @ChrisVasselli : Well nothing happened after I try to set contentSize in `viewDidLayoutSubviews:`. Looks like `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` is never getting called.

Comment: Woah, I never noticed all these comments before! Glad I could help so many of you out! I just posted a separate answer so hopefully it will be easier to find.

Comment: freak i was stuck with same problem for a week and the solution was to just remove check from autolayout facepalm

Comment: if i could +1 this answer 6 more times i would

Comment: Unchecking AutoLayout may work but it is not the correct solution. You SHOULD be switching to auto layout in your apps and if you want this to work you simply need to set contentSize inside viewDidLayoutSubviews in your view controller.

Comment: @ChrisVasselli your solution is the best so far :) This definitely should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: This isn't a solution. You're just turning off Autolayout. That's not a solution to people using Autolayout. We're supposed to be using Autolayout.

Comment: Bad Luck for me, no code worked for me But Putting code in viewDidLayoutSubviews after delay some seconds worked for me

Answer (score 69):

You need to set the `contentSize` property of the scroll view in order for it to scroll properly.

If you're using autolayout, you need to set `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in order for it to be applied after the autolayout completes.

The code could look like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // The scrollview needs to know the content size for it to work correctly
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(
        self.scrollContent.frame.size.width,
        self.scrollContent.frame.size.height + 300
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne.. This worked because for some reason, even when I set the value of `contentSize` to the size of `contentView`, the size of scrollView and contentView seems to get set as the same. But setting height of the `contentSize` to a value greater than the height of `contentView`, it worked.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can get called multiple times during a lifecycle so you run the risk increasing the height larger than expected.

Comment: @anon_nerd just check if it was called already and only add height if not

Answer (score 45):

The answer above is correct - to make scrolling happen, it's necessary to set the content size.

If you're using interface builder a neat way to do this is with user defined runtime attributes. Eg:

[image]

Comment: this didn't do anything for me.

Comment: Oops, the pic shows {0, 0}, but you of course have to put large enough numbers in. . . this approach will only work for simple views where you know the content-size up front. . . (in fact, for complex views I recommend pure code, anyway).

Comment: Much less hacky than doing it programmatically.  Thank you!

Comment: @JakeStoeffler welcome! :) When using IB, I like to keep all the config there (not fragmented). But when things get complex (reusable view widgets; model adapters, layer manipulations; CAAnimations, etc) then I prefer fully programmatic views. . .  more fluent.

Comment: I tried this, works when view appears, but on orientation change, the contentSize defined on the screen above is ignored and my log says the contentSize is set back 0,0. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Shoogle - see comment above ;) Just do it in code.

Comment: @JasperBlues: did not work for ios7. Any comment that may help me?

Comment: This will only work with auto-layout turned off. It's the equivalent of setting it in viewDidLoad before auto-layout has finish laying out the views. So... probably go with the `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` if using auto-layout.

Comment: @Chepe77 Don't put zeros of course - choose an appropriate size.

Answer (score 40):

Try to resize the content size to huge numbers. I couldn't understand why my scroll view doesn't scroll even when its content size seems to be bigger than control size. I discovered that if the content size is smaller than needed, it doesn't work also.

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000);
```

Instead of 2000 you can put your own big numbers. And if it works, it means that your content size is not big enough when you resize.

The delegate is not necessary for scroll view to work.

Comment: Genius - such a simple way to check what is going on. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you have the contentSize property of the scroll view set to the correct size (ie, one large enough to encompass all your content.)

Comment: do I have to do this programatically? or can I do it in IB?

Comment: If you're using IB, you can set it from there - see below. . (Separate answer, so I can include pics).

Answer (score 7):

Uncheck 'Use Autolayout' did the trick for me.

Environment:
xCode 5.0.2
Storyboards
ios7

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to set `delaysContentTouches` to true because the objects inside the scrollView were all capturing the touch events and handling themselves rather than letting the scrollView itself handle it.

Comment: I've the same issue. The problem for me is that by turning delaysContentTouches to true, you will end with lower quality drawings with an apple pencil. But this is a edge case :) in most cases it solve the issue

Answer (score 5):

Set `contentSize` property of `UIScrollview` in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Something like this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are getting a message (IOS8 / swift) that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` does not exist, use the following instead

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
```

This fixed it for me

Comment: do not put contentSize in  viewDidLoad its not gona work !!

Answer (score 3):

The idea of why scroll view is not scrolling because you set the content size for scrolling less than the size of the scroll view, which is wrong.
You should set the content size bigger than the size of your scroll view to navigate through it while scrolling.

The same idea with zooming, you set the min and max value for zooming which will applied through zooming action.

welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

One small addition, all above are the actual reasons why your scroll view might not be scrolling but sometimes mindlessly this could be the reason specially when scrollview is added through code and not IB, you might have added your subviews to the parent view and not to the scrollview this causes the subview to not scroll

and do keep the content size set and bigger than parent view frame (duhh!!)

Answer (score 3):

Add the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and adding the following code to the `viewDidAppear` method fixed it for me.

```
@interface testScrollViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made it working at my first try. With auto layout and everything, no additional code. Then a collection view went banana, crashing at run time, I couldn't find what was wrong, so I deleted and recreated it (I am using Xcode 10 Beta 4. It felt like a bug) and then the scrolling was gone. The Collection view worked again, though!

Many hours later.. this is what fixed it for me. I had the following layout:

**UIView**

- Safe Area
- Scroll view

  - Content view

It's all in the constraints. Safe Area is automatically defined by the system. In the worst case remove all constraints for scroll and content views and do **not** have IB resetting/creating them for you. Make them manually, it works.

- For Scroll view I did: **Align Trailing/Top to Safe Area. Equal Width/Height to Safe area**.
- For Content view I did: **Align Trailing/Leading/Top/Bottom to Superview (the scroll view)**

basically the concept is to have Content view fitting Scrollview, which is fitting Safe Area.

But as such it didn't work. Content view missed the height. I tried all I could and the only one doing the trick has been a **Content view height created control-dragging Content view.. to itself**. That defined a fixed height, which value has been computed from the Size of the the view controller (defined as freeform, longer than the real display, to containing all my subviews) and finally it worked again!

Comment: You're very welcome! I know exactly how you felt.. ;-)

Comment: Thaaaaks, I spent a lot of hours and this solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

My issue was resolved by:

1. setting the contentSize on the scrollView to a large height
2. BUT also I had to fix top and/or bottom constraints on views within the scrollView, which meant the scroll indicators showed on screen but the content did not scroll

Once I removed top and/or bottom constraints bound to the safe area and/or superview, the views inside the scrollView could scroll again and didn't stay fixed to the top of bottom of the screen!

Hope this stops someone else from hours of pain with this particular issue.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I was using a horizontal scrollview and my leading constraint of the first subview was constrained to the superview's leading anchor - not the scrollview's leading anchor.

Answer (score 3):

yet another fun case:

scrollview.superview.userInteractionEnabled must be true

I wasted 2+hrs chasing this just to figure out the parent
is UIImageView which, naturally, has userInteractionEnabled == false

Comment: Same case! you're a lifesaver. thanks a bunch!

Comment: yrw. even with cases like this its easier on ones nerves than programming droids

Comment: Right said. However, in my case, I had a UIScrollview inside a custom .xib based UIView subclass which was added on top of a UIImageView, which in turn, was a subview of a UIViewController's view, So I would hardly guess it was something to do with the UIImageView. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something that wasn't mentioned before!

Make sure your outlet was correctly connected to the scrollView! It should have a filled circle, but even if you have filled circle, scrollView may not been connected - so double check! Hover over the circle and see if the actual scrollview gets highlighted! (This was a case for me)

```
//Connect below well to the scrollView in the storyBoard
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alot of the time the code is correct if you have followed a tutorial but what many beginners do not know is that the scrollView is **NOT** going to scroll normally through the simulator. It is suppose to scroll only when you press down on the mousepad *and* simultaneously scroll. Many **Experienced** XCode/Swift/Obj-C users are so use to doing this and so they do not know how it could possibly be overlooked by beginners. Ciao :-)

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    // Do any additional setup after the view
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 800)
}
```

This code will work perfectly fine as long as you do what I said up above

Answer (score 1):

**If none of the other solutions work for you, double check that your scroll view actually is a `UIScrollView` in Interface Builder.**

At some point in the last few days, my `UIScrollView` **spontaneously changed type** to a `UIView`, even though its class said `UIScrollView` in the inspector.  I'm using `Xcode 5.1 (5B130a)`.

You can either create a new scroll view and copy the measurements, settings and constraints from the old view, or you can manually change your view to a `UIScrollView` in the `xib` file.  I did a compare and found the following differences:

**Original:**

```
<scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" directionalLockEnabled="YES" bounces="NO" pagingEnabled="YES" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" showsVerticalScrollIndicator="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Wsk-WB-LMH">
...
</scrollView>
```

**After type spontaneously changed:**

```
<view clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" customClass="UIScrollView" id="qRn-TP-cXd">
...
</view>
```

So I replaced the `<view>` line with my original `<scrollView>` line.

I also replaced the view's close tag `</view>` with `</scrollView>`.

**Be sure to keep the id the same as the current view, in this case: id="qRn-TP-cXd".**

I also had to flush the xib from Xcode's cache by deleting the app's derived data:

- `Xcode->Window->Organizer->Projects`, choose your project, on the Derived Data line, click Delete...

Or if using a device:

- `Xcode->Window->Organizer->Device`, choose your device->Applications, choose your app, click (-)

Now clean the project, and remove the app from the simulator/device:

- `Xcode->Product->Clean`
- iOS `Simulator/device->press` and hold the `app->click` the (X) to remove it

You should then be able to build and run your app and have scrolling functionality again.

P.S. I didn't have to set the scroll view's content size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or turn off auto layout, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If your `scrollView` is a subview of a `containerView` of some type, then make sure that your `scrollView` is within the frame or bounds of the `containerView`. I had `containerView.clipsToBounds = NO` which still allowed me see the scrollView, but because `scrollView` wasn't within the bounds of `containerView` it wouldn't detect touch events.

For example:

```
containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 200);
[containerView addSubview:scrollView];
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

You will be able to see the scrollView but it won't receive user interactions.

Answer (score 1):

adding the following code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked for me with Autolayout. After trying all the answers:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.activationScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(IPHONE_SCREEN_WIDTH, 620);

}

//set the height of content size as required
```

Answer (score 1):

**The straightforward programmatically way**

To wrap it up

Create a `UIScrollView`

```
private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return scrollView
}()
```

Use a Single Child View to Hold All of Your Content Subviews

```
private lazy var contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()
```

Add your views

```
contentView.addSubview(firstSubView)
contentView.addSubview(lastSubView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Usually, you only want your content to scroll in one direction. In most cases to scroll vertically. Therefore set the width of the content view to be the width of the scroll view.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
```

Attach four constraints (top, bottom, left, right) from our single content view to the scroll view.

```
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
```

Make sure you have **constraints attached to all four sides of the content view** so that it will expand to the size of your content.

```
// After Adding your subviews to the contentView make sure you've those two constraints set:

    firstSubView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    .
    .
    .
    lastSubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Reference: [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

After failing with the provided answers in this thread, I stumbled upon [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) with the solution.

There are two things not intuitive about setting up the scrollview with autolayout:

1. The constraints you set up as margin between the contentview and scrollview do not influence the size of the contentview. They really are margins. And to make it work, the contentview should have a fixed size.
2. The trick to the fixed size is that you can set the width of the contentview equal to that of the scrollview's parent. Just select both views in the tree on the left and add the equal widths constraint.

This is the gist of that article. For a complete explanation, including illustrations, check it out.

Comment: @PredragManojlovic How can it get more general than this? This is the only way I could get the scrollview to get to work properly, using auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with this AutoLayout issue... if I just make the `ViewController` use `UIView` instead of `UIScrollView` for the class... then just add a `UIScrollView` myself... that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in IB.

After setting the leading, trailing, top and bottom of the scrollView to its superView. I made the following changes to make the containerView scrollable, which worked.

To make the scrollView only scroll on horizontal direction make the constraint with scrollView's centerY = ContainerView's centerY

and to make it vertically scrollable make the scrollView's centerX = ContainerView's centerX

Answer (score 0):

> You don’t have to set the content size of the scroll view.

[Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone made the same mistake like me, I'd like to share my case.

In my case, I mistakenly add a constraint to one of the subviews of scrollview which makes the subview's space to the topLayoutGuide fixed, thus it's location can't be changed, so the scrollview can't be scrolled.