# Can't get UIScrollView to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

This is a storyboard app. I added a `UIScrollView` on top of the `UIView` that is there in the view controller by default. Then I added some UI elements on to the scroll view. After designing the viewable part of the Scroll view, using its handles I stretched it vertically and pushed it up a bit so that that part is visible for me to design the rest of the screen. After I was done I positioned the scroll view back to fit the view. Please note that I did not resize the scroll view to match the size of the view from the IB.

Then I added all 4 constraints to the scroll view (Leading and Trailing space to superview, Top and Bottom space to superview). Then I selected the `UIView`, opened up the size inspector and changed the Bottom Space to superview's value to 0. That automatically resized the `UIScrollView` to fit inside the view controller.

Then I added the following lines of code inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

But this does not work. The `UIScrollView` won't scroll. Yes, the scrolling is enabled.

Can anyone please tell me what I might be missing here?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I found an old project of mine [here](http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/37137086/file.html). It utilize the way I just explained above and it works! No idea why it doesn't anymore.

I also added a [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/331p2qesc65inrj/ScrollViewTest.zip) here with the issue.

Comment: you have set the content size and frame the same.. so scrollview wont scroll.

Comment: In addition, during `viewDidLoad` the views are not fully laid out so the dimensions (frame) is not set. Try putting your code in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @bobnoble You're right. I moved the code in to `viewDidAppear` method and hardcoded the value for `self.scrollView.frame.size.height` with 700 and it works now. What I don't understand is, my previous way worked for me in the past. I found an old project of mine (here)[http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/37137086/file.html]. In it, I have it inside `viewDidLoad` and no hardcoded values.

Comment: @Isuru - in the example project you provided the link to, the scroll view `contentSize` height is hard coded with `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 627);`.

Comment: If you replace it with `self.scrollView.frame.size.height`, it still works. I really don't like hardcoding values. That's why I'm looking for a way to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your code correctly (a screenshot of the view would help) you set the scrollviews frame to be full size of the view and set then contentSize to the view's size. A scrollview scrolls only if the contentSize is larger than its size.

Comment: I have a demo Xcode project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/331p2qesc65inrj/ScrollViewTest.zip) if you could please take a look at.

Comment: Looks ok for me - the main screen scrolls vertically

Comment: I hardcoded the scrollview's height and moved theose 2 lines to `viewDidAppear` method. Now it works. The weird thing is I found [this](http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/37137086/file.html) old project of mine working just fine with no hardcoded values and while in the `viewDidLoad` method! Is there any way I can get this to work without hardcoding the scrollview's height?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the complete answer to your question, but it will help you and others for sure.

To design the views that are bigger in size than the size of the `UIScrollView`, the best way to  have the `UIView` as a child view to `UIScrollView` and put all the content on the `UIView` and finally place the UIView as subview of the `UISCrollView`. AT last you can set the size of the UIView as the content size of the `UISCrollView`.

Cheers. :)