# scroll view control in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, contentsize

I am new to iOS, 
Am facing an issue with `UIScrollView`. The scroll is not working in this, can you please help me:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 310,300, 999)];

label.text = self.selString;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
// [self.view addSubview:label];

UIImageView *image = 
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 300)];
image.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
image.tag = 50;
image.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
image.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
image.alpha = 0.93;
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opensum.in/app_test_f1/45djx96.jpg"]]];   // working code
//[self.view addSubview:image];

self.title = @"Full Blog";

CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 999);
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
scrollView.pagingEnabled =YES;
[self.view  addSubview:scrollView];

scrollView.tag=1000;


[scrollView addSubview:label];
[scrollView addSubview:image];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView not scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824435/uiscrollview-not-scrolling)

Answer (score 4):

Set `UIScrollView` `contentSize` :

```
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 1000);
[scrollView setContentSize:contentSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView`. Without setting that, it' won't show scrolling. And your contentSize should be bigger than your `scrollView.frame.size`.

Right now, your `scrollView` has a huge frame.height. Use a smaller value. And use the higher value for contentSize.height.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 310,300, 999)];

label.text=self.selString;
label.numberOfLines=0;

UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 300)];
image.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
image.tag = 50;
image.alpha = 0.93;
image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://opensum.in/app_test_f1/45djx96.jpg"]]];

CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 999);
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
scrollView.tag=1000;

[scrollView addSubview:image];
[scrollView addSubview:label];
[self.view  addSubview:scrollView];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 999);// your scroll scroll height give here
```

Answer (score 1):

set content height of scrollview like this

```
[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 999))];
```